# Why does this ASP.NET Web Handler not receive the POST request?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, post

I was looking at an ASP.NET app example that someone else wrote, which basically consists of an HTML file sending an AJAX POST request to a Web Handler - which is then supposed to process the request and send back a message to say that it was received successfully.

However, this example code seems to return a "500 status (Internal Server Error)", and i really can't seem to figure out why. Would someone kindly review the code and tell me why this is happening? I would *really* appreciate it.

I wanted analyse the code to use it in a search engine project, which is supposed to send a user input string from a front-end html form to the Web Handler, this string would then be processed and sent to a crawler which would crawl sites from a database and return the sites which have the highest volume of the key-word.

Here is the HTML file with the AJAX POST request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <title>Search Engine</title>
</head>
<body>
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td><label id="From" />From : </td>
           <td><input id="TxtFrom"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><label id="To" />To : </td>
           <td><input id="TxtTo" required="required"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><label id="To" />Body : </td>
           <td>
               <textarea id="TxtBody" required="required"
                         rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td />
           <td style="align-content:flex-end">
               <button onclick="loadJsonData();">Send Data to the Server</button>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
   <script>
       function loadJsonData() {
           var postdata = JSON.stringify(
               {
                   "From": document.getElementById("TxtFrom").value,
                   "To": document.getElementById("TxtTo").value,
                   "Body": document.getElementById("TxtBody").value
               });
           try {
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "MailHandler.ashx",
                   cache: false,
                   data: postdata,
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: getSuccess,
                   error: getFail
               });
           } catch (e) {
               alert(e);
           }
           function getSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               alert(data.Response);
           };
           function getFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert(jqXHR.status);
           };
       };
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Web Handler (MailHandler.ashx):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace CodeProject
{
    public class MailHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string jsonString = String.Empty;
            HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            using (System.IO.StreamReader inputStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
            {
                jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSerialize = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                var email = jSerialize.Deserialize<Mail>(jsonString);

                if (email != null)
                {
                    string froma = email.From;
                    string to = email.To;
                    string body = email.Body;

                    context.Response.Write(jSerialize.Serialize(
                         new
                         {
                             Response = "Message Has been sent succesfully"
                         }));
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Web Config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies />
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: take a look at the response to the request in the browser developer tools, if ASP.NET is configured to do so, it will send a very detailed error in the response body

Comment: You must find out the details of the 500 error. It's hard for anyone to help if we don't know what it is that's failing.

Comment: Currently this is what it is giving back in the console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)". I will look around and try to get a more detailed response.

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint on the ProcessRequest handler? Do you get an hit on the breakpoint? Or if you cannot debug that code, add logging to see if the request reaches the server.

Comment: Just added a breakpoint where you said, it seems that it doesn't get a hit. Meaning it doesn't reach the server.

Comment: You haven't share your entire handler. You shared the method, but not the class definition, nor the .ascx directives. Please provide a true [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that, just updated to include the whole handler code in my question.

Comment: have you tried to change the url to `MailHandler.ashx/ProcessRequest` and  for the data use `{ context: {....}}`.

Comment: Just changed the url and nothing seems to have resolved, could you please elaborate on what you said about how the data is being used?

Comment: the data should start with the method signature name as `{context: { postdata here }}`

Comment: Just tried to refactor the data like you suggested and the request still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Yarik make sure you've added the handler in the web.config under the `httpHandlers`.

Comment: I've just updated the question to include my web.config, it doesn't seem to include the handler, how do you suggest adding the MailHandler?

Comment: under `system.web` add `<httpHandlers><add verb="GET,POST" path="MailHandler.ashx"  validate="false" type="MailHandler" /></httpHandlers>`.

Comment: Still no luck, it gave the 500 response after I put I added the handler.

Comment: @iSR5 If you're using an ashx generic handler, there's no need to register it in web.config. And there's no need to add the method name into the URL - that paradigm only applies to ASMX files.

Comment: Are you sure you provided us with the .ashx file contents? It looks like you've provided .ashx.cs file, the code behind. We need to see both.

Comment: I assure you that is the complete code file with all the contents. The example only consisted of the html file and the handler file, everything was made when the web app was made. Here is the original source: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/832696/How-to-send-Data-from-JavaScript-to-Csharp-Server

Comment: could you try adding this to your URL path: "<%= ResolveUrl("~/MailHandler.ashx") %>" ?